# Show that the set of algebraic numbers is countable(Proof verification)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I just want to make sure that my proof is good. There is a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}^n$ into $X^n$ given by $\phi : \mathbb{Q}^n \rightarrow X^n = \{ x^n + a_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + ... + a_0 : a_i \in \mathbb{Q} \}$, where $(a_{n - 1},...,a_0) \mapsto x^n + a_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} +\ ...\ + a_0$.

It is clear that this is a bijection. The set of all polynomials of degree n with coeffient 1 on the highest degree term is countable. Since it is in bijection with $\mathbb{Q}^n$, which is countable. Since each $X^n$ is countable countable unions of it is countable hence there is a bijection $\theta : \bigcup X^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_+$.

Let A_n be the algebraic numbers of all polynomials of degree n. We wish to show that $A_n$ is countable. Since $X^n$ is countable there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and $X^n$. Therefore there exists a bijection $\eta : X^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_+$, which means $A_n = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_+} A_{\eta(i)\ n}$, where $A_{\eta(i)\ n}$ is the solutions of the ith polynomial. Since this is union of countable sets A_n is countable, which means that $A^{\infty} = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_+} A_i$ is countable as it is countable unions of countable sets. That means that algebraic numbers are countable.

Comment: That is the right idea.  The set of polynomials (with rational coefficients) is countable.  So the set of roots of said polynomials is countable.

Comment: It would be good to mention explicitly that any polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ distinct roots. Also, you need to modify your argument to take account of the fact that every algebraic number occurs as a root of many of our polynomials. So we obtain a surjection from the algebraic numbers to the naturals, which can then be turned into a bijection.  By the way, not that it changes anything of significance, we can assume the coefficients of the polynomials are integers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments I have changed it a little bit. Sorry for my late reply I had problems with my internet.